# Can I update non-xml config files using msbuild?

Tags: msbuild, configuration-files

I have a config file which has an old stylee format (no xml)

```
dbpath=C:\Program Files\Mongodb\Data\Db
journal=true
smallfiles=true
```

Depending on the system I am releasing too I want to update and change the values after the =

Is this possible with MSbuild? Can you show me how?

I know how to do this using xml poke for xml config files.

Comment: I would use Xml Task to write some basic xml, and then use a xsl to transform it.  It's not a better idea then the "write out a text file" idea, but writing lines 1 by 1 in a text file.....feels wrong to me in 2013.  Just a suggestion, not looking for a fight :O

Comment: Look at my answer (not my question) at this post for writing some basic xml.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13867117/how-to-add-a-linked-file-to-a-csproj-file-with-msbuild-3-5-framework

Comment: xslt gives me hives :) Thanks for the idea though!

Comment: I use it less and less, but for small things like this....I'm still good with it.  Except for easy things, its so hard to go back and maintain.  So my rule is if I can't re-figure it out in an hour, then the xsl is probably too complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set up a template system  and use the detokenise from the msbuild extension pack. See the Documentation here:[http://www.msbuildextensionpack.com/help/4.0.6.0/Index.html](http://www.msbuildextensionpack.com/help/4.0.6.0/html/348d3976-920f-9aca-da50-380d11ee7cf5.htm)

That would mean you wouldn't have to write custom targets like above all the time

So youd have:

```
 <ItemGroup>
      <Transforms Include="$(ReleasePath)\Yourtemplates\**"/>
    </ItemGroup>


    <MSBuild.ExtensionPack.FileSystem.Detokenise
      TaskAction="Detokenise"
      TargetFiles="%(Transforms.FullPath)"/>
```

Comment: I think this is probably the correct way of doing things though I am leaving it my hacky way until I need to revisit the problem

Answer (score 1):

Nothing like asking a question to help you answer it!

I am going to do this

```
<Target Name="UpdateConfig">
    <CreateProperty Value="..\config.cfg">
         <Output TaskParameter="Value" PropertyName="path" />
    </CreateProperty>

    <Message Text="LogFilePath=$(LogFilePath)"/>

    <FileUpdate Files="$(path)"
        Regex="logpath=.*"
        ReplacementText="logpath=$(LogFilePath)" />
</Target>
```

It is not what I would call elegant but I don't find much about msbuild that is!

Got a better suggestion?

Comment: You could template it and use the detokenise from the msbuild extension pack. That would mean you wouldn't have to write custom targets like above all the time.

Comment: Looks like a good solution... make an answer and I will upvote you!

Answer (score 1):

Write your own MSBuild task,

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9883dzc(v=VS.90).aspx

And then reference it in your MSBuild scripts.

Comment: The reason I like this idea is that it would be a good way to learn how to create your own MSBuild task.  It's small enough to bite off.