# Adding MSBuild generated files to Visual Studio Solution Explorer

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, msbuild

I have a couple of MSBuild tasks that generate new files during the build. The custom targets add the files to the Compile ItemGroup after they are generated. So the build will work if my targets are ran, but I want to use the incremental building features of MSBuild and skip these targets if the files haven't been modified since the last build. But if the build skips the target the generated files won't be included.

So I want to have the build add the files to the solution explorer. I realize I can add the files manually, and that might be the route I have to go, but I would really like to have the generated files added programmatically.

I currently have a file called Custom.targets. It is included in every project and injects the new targets. I have tried including *.cs in the project, but that did not work.

Comment: Are you talking about adding "entries" to the csproj file?  Or .sln file?  or what?

Comment: These would be entries in the csproj file.

Comment: You can follow the answer (that I left for my own question) here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13867117/how-to-add-a-linked-file-to-a-csproj-file-with-msbuild-3-5-framework            I used an Msbuild (xmlupdate) task to add a "linked file" through msbuild code.

Comment: Ooops.  I added a linked file......you can alter my code to add whatever you want....... but the premise is... you just call the task to manipulate the xml.  I would get the source code for the Target I use, it makes sense of what is happening.......with the DOM manipulation.

Comment: I think if you call the `Targets` imported through `Custom.targets` in `BeforeBuild` in your `*.csproj` file and then adding a `Compile` `ItemGroup` as following will include any `*.cs` file which gets generated by `Custom.targets` into `*.csproj` file folder or any folder under that. `<Compile Include="**\*.cs" />`. If you want to go folders above *csproj file folder, then try     `<Compile Include="..\**\*.cs" />`. Number of `..\\` will depend on the number of folder levels you want to go up

Comment: @RinoTom That works in making sure during builds that it references any already generated files. But that doesn't add the files to visual studio explorer. This causes intellisense to complain about missing methods that are actually there, but just hidden in the generated files. granadaCoder I didn't think you were allowed to edit .csproj files as they were being run? do you have a seperate msbuild script that modifies your csproj file?

Comment: Yes, the code (at the other link) is in my custom msbuild (.proj) file...........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing something similar to granadaCoder. I just decided to do it inside of a custom task instead of only in xml. I ensure that 3 files are included in the project, FilePath, BinPath and HooksPath. If all of them are there, nothing happens. If it is missing one it adds it to the ItemGroup and saves the document. The document save can't happen during a build. So it requires running the build again after any save.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using Microsoft.Build.Framework;
using Microsoft.Build.Utilities;

namespace BuildTasks
{
    public class AddFilesToProject : Task
    {
        [Required]
        public string ProjectPath { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string FilePath { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string BinPath { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string HooksPath { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string ProjectDir { get; set; }


        /// <summary>
        /// When overridden in a derived class, executes the task.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>
        /// true if the task successfully executed; otherwise, false.
        /// </returns>
        public override bool Execute()
        {

            try
            {
                var binRelative = BinPath.Replace(ProjectDir + "\\", "");
                var hooksRelative = HooksPath.Replace(ProjectDir + "\\", "");
                var fileRelative = FilePath.Replace(ProjectDir + "\\", "");
                XDocument document = XDocument.Load(ProjectPath);
                XNamespace ns = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003";

                bool foundBin = false;
                bool foundHooks = false;
                bool foundFile = false;
                XElement itemGroup = null;
                foreach (XElement el in document.Descendants(ns + "ItemGroup"))
                {
                    foreach (XElement item in el.Descendants(ns + "Compile"))
                    {
                        itemGroup = el;
                        if (item.Attribute("Include").Value.Contains(binRelative))
                        {
                            foundBin = true;
                            Log.LogMessage(MessageImportance.Low, "FoundBin: {0}", foundBin);
                        }
                        else if (item.Attribute("Include").Value.Contains(hooksRelative))
                        {
                            foundHooks = true;
                            Log.LogMessage(MessageImportance.Low, "FoundHooks: {0}", foundHooks);
                        }
                        else if (item.Attribute("Include").Value.Contains(fileRelative))
                        {
                            foundFile = true;
                            Log.LogMessage(MessageImportance.Low, "FoundFile: {0}", foundFile);
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (!foundBin)
                {
                    XElement item = new XElement(ns + "Compile");
                    item.SetAttributeValue("Include", binRelative);
                    if (itemGroup != null) itemGroup.Add(item);
                }
                if (!foundHooks)
                {
                    XElement item = new XElement(ns + "Compile");
                    item.SetAttributeValue("Include", hooksRelative);
                    if (itemGroup != null) itemGroup.Add(item);
                }
                if (!foundFile)
                {
                    XElement item = new XElement(ns + "Compile");
                    item.SetAttributeValue("Include", fileRelative);
                    if (itemGroup != null) itemGroup.Add(item);                    
                }
                if (!foundBin || !foundHooks || !foundFile)
                {
                    document.Save(ProjectPath);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Log.LogErrorFromException(e);
            }

            return !Log.HasLoggedErrors;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not to allow exception to go upper?